# sqlcmd truncating row width when export to csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Am running sql query using sqlcmd and redirecting output to csv file. It seems my csv file truncating each row by 257 characters eventhough I gave "-w 8192" as argument.

```
sqlcmd -i jira.sql -o JiraQueryResult.csv -h-1 -w 8192 -Y 8000
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by following

```
sqlcmd -i jira.sql -o JiraQueryResult.csv -h-1 -y 8000
```

Thanks